# Rebuild select options by ajax request to mobius1-selectr

Tags: jquery, ajax, select, input, components

Using mobius1-selectr (https://github.com/Mobius1/Selectr)

Hi, I don't know if I am writing the right code for do this.
I have 3 selects that needs to be filled by jquery based on a result from another select.
I am trying to use the new function with data, but the element don't reload new options content.

I have this element:

`<select id="dimensions_ids" multiple class="form-control hidden-input" name="dimensions_ids[]" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" disabled=""><option value="0"></option></select>`

> One option is needed because I can't create a selectr without any option.

So, first I am initializing the element like this:

`let selectDimensionsIds = new Selectr('#dimensions_ids', {
        clearable: true
    });
    selectDimensionsIds.disable();`

An I am trying to do this, but the options won refresh:

`function populateDimensions(areasId) {
        let values = {
            'areas': areasId
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: '/getdimensionsbyareas',
            type: 'GET',
            data: values,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result) {
                let dimensions = JSON.stringify(result);
                selectDimensionsIds.destroy();
               selectDimensionsIds = new Selectr('#dimensions_ids', {
                    dimensions,
                    clearable: true,
                    multiple: true
                });
                selectDimensionsIds.enable();
            },
        });
    }`

If someone could help me. I appreciate. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I did this and solved my problem.

```
function populateDimensions(areasId) {
    let values = {
        'areas': areasId
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: '/getdimensionsbyareas',
        type: 'GET',
        data: values,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) {
            let selectHtml = '';
            if (result.data.length > 0) {
                $.each(result.data, function (index, value) {
                    selectHtml += '<optgroup label="' + value.text + '">';
                    $.each(value.children, function (index, value) {
                        selectHtml += '<option value="' + value.value + '">' + value.text + '</option>';
                    });
                });
                selectDimensionsIds.destroy();
                $('#dimensions_ids').empty();
                $('#dimensions_ids').append(selectHtml);
                selectDimensionsIds.render({
                    clearable: true,
                    multiple: true
                });
                selectDimensionsIds.enable();
            } else {
                selectDimensionsIds.destroy();
                $('#dimensions_ids').empty();
                $('#dimensions_ids').append('<option>Selecione uma ou mais áreas</option>');
                selectDimensionsIds.render({
                    clearable: true,
                    multiple: true
                });
                selectDimensionsIds.disable();
            }
        },
    });
}
```